# Python IndexError: list index out of range при обработке JSON

Tags: python, json

Делаю, вроде бы, элементарную вещь:

```
import requests
import json

full_url = 'example.com'
i = 0

r = requests.get(full_url, verify=False)
data = r.json()

while ( i < int(data["TotalRecords"])) :
        print data["Data"][i]["id"]
        i += 1

exit (0)
```

**В результате "IndexError: list index out of range"**.

Цикл дохнет при достижении i значения 100.
Всего выгружается порядка 3000 элементов.

**Обновление**

На небольших данных всё ОК.
Кусок json'a:

```
{map': {}, Data': [
{p2': 22, pr': 6, p1': 51373, no': snort', index': sessions-141208', db': 286864, id': 141208-UAs05h4pNJJDep-jtXy6f9rp', a1': 167773389, pa': 3532, fp': 1418025877, lp': 1418027319, ro': 141208-UAuzrBogdHBHQ59kpsVMuYNr', by': 871656, a2': 168427595}, 
{p2': 22, pr': 6, p1': 51373, no': snort', index': sessions-141208', db': 335312, id': 141208-UAsUDoftJ-5CVIqfH1t5rmaN', a1': 167773389, pa': 6216, fp': 1418025877, lp': 1418028038, ro': 141208-UAuzrBogdHBHQ59kpsVMuYNr', by': 3211128, a2': 168427595}
```

Comment: Попробовали бы сперва на маленьких данных отладить.

По теме без исходного json ничего сказать нельзя.

Comment: упс, не тот json втавил

{map': {}, Data': [
{p2': 22, pr': 6, p1': 51373, no': snort', index': sessions-141208', db': 286864, id': 141208-UAs05h4pNJJDep-jtXy6f9rp', a1': 167773389, pa': 3532, fp': 1418025877, lp': 1418027319, ro': 141208-UAuzrBogdHBHQ59kpsVMuYNr', by': 871656, a2': 168427595}, 
{p2': 22, pr': 6, p1': 51373, no': snort', index': sessions-141208', db': 335312, id': 141208-UAsUDoftJ-5CVIqfH1t5rmaN', a1': 167773389, pa': 6216, fp': 1418025877, lp': 1418028038, ro': 141208-UAuzrBogdHBHQ59kpsVMuYNr', by': 3211128, a2': 168427595}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*упс, был неправ.*

Скорее всего дело в том, что на сервере используется разбивание на страницы. Просто на страницу выводится максимум сто элементов, независимо от того, сколько их на самом деле.

Неплохо бы пользоваться правильным питоновским путём, `for`:

```
for element in data["Data"]:
    print element["id"]
```

Читай [документацию](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Comment: Спасибо!
Про разбитие на  страницы не подумал)